# Apache Camel Regex to check if line contains alphabets

Tags: regex

My Fuse blueprint is reading from CSV. I am trying to filter out lines that does not have any text.i.e. line with just ',' using regex.

Code

```
<choice id="_choice1">
   <when id="_when1">
      <simple>${body} regex '[a-z].*'</simple>
         <log id="_log1" message="Data --> ${body}"/>
   </when>
   <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
     <log id="_log2" message="otherwise --> ${body}"/>
   </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Data from CSV  below.

```
Textbox1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Report Date  11/05/2016,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
SiteCode,Site_Description,SiteModulesComplted,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
123,abc,my site, java training,
```

Output

```
INFO  otherwise --> Textbox1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
INFO  otherwise --> Report Date  11/05/2016,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
INFO  otherwise --> ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
INFO  otherwise --> SiteCode,Site_Description,SiteModulesComplted,
```

What I am experiencing is all lines are routed to otherwise. Not sure what I have done wrong with regex.

If someone can please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[a-z].*` means a single lowercase character followed by any characters.  None of the above matches (because the lines with text start with uppercase characters)

How about `.*[a-zA-Z].*`?

Comment: Tried that does not work. Also tried regex '^[A-Z].*' and regex '^[a-zA-Z].*$'

Comment: Does body contain a line of text or the whole text?

Comment: I got it working. Issue was something else. Thank you for you help and time.